# how is the air pressure that exerted to our body cancels out?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

i didn't understand it how the air pressure cancel out.my eye is so sensitive,and why is the air pressure that comes towards my face doesn't hurt my eye? why is our body doesn't feel a thing while the air pressure being exerted?

Comment: Because the internal pressure of the body is approximately the same ...

Answer (score 1):

Think about a sheet of paper held loosely horizontally.  There are about 14.7 pounds of pressure pushing down on every square inch of the top surface.  For a 8½ x 11 inch paper, that comes out to about 1,400 pounds.  The reason that paper isn't ripped out of your hand and slammed to the ground is because the same pressure is also pushing up on the bottom side.

The various parts of your body, and any other objects lying around, work the same way.  The air pressure is pushing all around, and the net force is 0.

Well, almost 0.  Air pressure decreases with altitude.  For large enough objects, the force pushing down on the top is noticeably less than the force pushing up at the bottom.  If you do all the math, you find that the net upward force is directly proportional to the volume of the object.  Blimps and helium-filled party balloons exploit this principle and are actually able to rise thru the air against gravity.